# Redirect the home page

Tags: wordpress, velo

I am currently using AWS Cloud. I have my Wordpress Site and WIX Site have similar pages.

Is this possible if someone connect to www.sampledomain/home1 it will redirect to wordpress and if someone connect to www.sampledomain/home2 it will redirect to wix?